# super dealloc on ARC subclasses

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

In ARC I'm aware that you do not call `[super dealloc]` in any overrides of `-dealloc`, so typically I remove observers and timers in there without doing so. However, if I were to subclass a view that I made that releases observation info in `-dealloc` without calling `[super dealloc]` in the subclass' implementation of the method, would the super implementation be called automatically to release the observation info handled by the superclass, or would it leak?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The superclass' implementation of `dealloc` is automatically called (as far as I know, the compiler inserts the statement `[super dealloc]` for you).

[External link to LLVM docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#dealloc)

#### Update

Here is the reference:

> Custom dealloc methods in ARC do not require a call to [super dealloc] (it actually results in a compiler error). The chaining to super is automated and enforced by the compiler. [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226)

[image]

Comment: Yes, I confirm that. It first called child's dealloc and then parent dealloc.