# How i set ARC Tag in Xcode project file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

IN my Xcode Project When i'm build the Project there is error occure aaas ARC forbids explicit message send of 'dealloc' ABC.m,in my ABC.m file i'm using [super dealloc] statment So,how i solve  this error.

Comment: a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377522/super-dealloc-on-arc-subclasses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add -fno-objc-arc in Build phase --> particular viewcontroller.m --> dobule click on that m file and write down -fno-objc-arc